# N64 Controller Won't Work in ROMs on Retropie 4.1

Tags: retropie

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 running Retropie 4.1. I just purchased an N64 controller for the N64 ROMs that I have. I configured the input and I can now navigate around the Retropie menu but when I go into a ROM, it won't respond to the controller. Is there a step I missed? Everything I find online is for Retropie 2 or 3.

Pi Model or other hardware: Raspberry Pi 3 Model B
Power Supply used: 5V 2.5A
RetroPie Version Used : 4.1
Built From: Pre made SD Image on RetroPie website
USB Devices connected: MAYFLASH N64 Controller Adapter For Pc
Controller used: Original Nintendo 64 Controller

UPDATE: I switched to the lr-glupen64 emulator and now I can *sort of * play with the Nintendo 64 controller. The joystick isn't sensitive enough though. Example: I can't turn really well in Mario Kart 64.

Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I bought a mayflash N64 adapter to use my OEM N64 controllers. They work in the menu. But not in the ROMs. I'm also using pi3 retro 4.1. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is old, but i found out the reson behind the joystick senseitivity. Its because of the so called "Deadzone". The playstation analog is set differently. Its all below in this link.

https://retropie.org.uk/forum/topic/126/n64-controller-analogue-stick-issues

Answer (score 0):

This may not be much of a solution but often a lot of older Nintendo 64 controllers have the plastic casing of the joystick worn away due to aggressive spinning, and lack the sensitivity they had when they're new. If this controller has been used a lot in the past, it might be an issue there rather than the Pi or any software it's running.

Comment: I appreciate the response but it's a brand new controller that I was initially testing with. The same is happening with all n64 controllers that I have tried, old and new.